# how to use shared preferences to save array list items?

Tags: java, android, arrays, list

I use these 2 methods for save and load my array list and  I need to save my array list after each item dynamically added to array.

```
 public void addItems(int howMany){
            if (howMany > 0) {
                int lastInsertedIndex = 11;
                for (int i = lastInsertedIndex + 1; i <= lastInsertedIndex + howMany; i++) {
                    mList.add("Item " + i);
                    notifyItemInserted(mList.size() - 1);
                }
                lastInsertedIndex = lastInsertedIndex + howMany;
            }
        }
```

and my save and load method:

```
public boolean saveArray() {
        SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        set.addAll(mainListAdapter.mList);
        editor.putStringSet("list", set);
        return editor.commit();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getArray() {
        SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        //NOTE: if shared preference is null, the method return empty Hashset and not null
        Set<String> set = sp.getStringSet("list", new HashSet<String>());
        return new ArrayList<String>(set);
    }
```

My problem is : when I add a new item with button nothing happen and like the array list is full how to fix this ?

Comment: I use a for loop to save lists to shared prefs, with the key as the index number in the list. I can't code from my phone, though it should be easy to search for. Something similar to put.String(i, mList.get(i));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The the following:

Declare `myList` globally:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

For setting value:

```
for (int i = 0; i < totalSize; i++) {
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
                     .edit()
                     .putString("number" + i, value + "").commit();         
}
```

For getting value:

```
for (int i = 0; i < totalSize; i++) {
   myList.add(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
                               .getString("number" + i, "0"));
}
```

**NOTE:- `totalSize` is the size of your array**

enjoy coding.............

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using [TinyDB](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo), it's an implementation of `SharedPreferences` and is very simple to use.

```
TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(context);
tinydb.putList("identifier", list);
```

You can even save objects:

```
tinydb.putObject(key, object);
tinydb.putListObject(key, objectsArray);
```